# How does indexedRDD in spark compare to SnappyData?

Tags: apache-spark, snappydata

What is the status of the indexedRDD work in Spark? Has anyone looked at [SnappyData](https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappydata)? They make some claims around being able to do fast random reads and writes on dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/amplab/spark-indexedrdd) is the Amplab work on IndexedRdd. There are no commits to this project since Sept 2015 and seems like the approach required re-scans of the entire RDD to construct a new one on each update. 
See [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2629?jql=text%20~%20%22indexedRDD%22) for how state management will be addressed in a future version of Spark (likely Spark 2.0). This relies on checkpointing RDD state at configured intervals.
But, it is more advisable to consider a third party data store for random RW like [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/), [GemFire](http://pivotal.io/big-data/pivotal-gemfire), [Redis](http://redis.io/), etc. 
[SnappyData](https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappydata), an in-memory SQL datastore, is also in this camp but also permits the data store to run embedded within spark executors avoiding serialization/deserialization issues.